# Programmatically downloading and installing an update apk giving a null error in my try-catch block

Tags: android

I am building an android application and I want to be able to programmatically download an update whenever it is available. My code used to work, but now it does not and I'm not sure where I went wrong.

I checked online for alternatives and I tried the code below.

```
private void updateApplication(String apkUrl){
    try {
        Log.d("hi", "doInBackGround started -- application updating");
        URL url = new URL(apkUrl);
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();

        File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        file.mkdirs();
        File outputFile = new File(file, "sampleFileName.apk");
        if(outputFile.exists()){
            outputFile.delete();
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len1 = 0;

        while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        }

        fos.close();
        is.close();

        Log.d("hi", "file downloaded successfully");

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(outputFile),
            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("UpdateAPP", "Update error! " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to download the file then install it. However, what happens is that my code goes through to the `catch` block and my LogCat looks like:

```
doInBackGround started -- application updating
Update error! null
```

As you can see, the try block was entered but it goes to a catch block and I don't know where it breaks off.

How can I update my application?

### Edit

I used the `outputFile` variable when I try to execute my apk file.

However, when I placed log statements all over my code, the app stops at the `c.connect();` line. My permission files are as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can't see anything obvious but are you saving the file as 'sampleFileName.apk' and then trying to open 'app.apk'? Is the file failing to be found at all.

Comment: ^Woah you have a point there. Wait. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Make sure to also print the stacktrace of the exception (i.e. `e.printStackTrace()`). Even if there is no message, the trace will contain useful information like the call hierarchy, exception type etc.

Comment: Looks like your download and open folder might be different as well.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) vs Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/". Best to make them use the same environmental constants. In case just the changing fails.

Comment: I edited my question for an update. It seems that I can't connect to the url I provide.

Comment: Okay I'm an idiot. forgot to place this in an Async Task

Answer (score 0):

As MH suggested, I printed my stacktrace and I saw that the error was a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. I think the reason why the catch block was generating a `null` report is because the catch statement wasn't looking for those kind of throwables.

Here's a pseudocode of my solution:

1. Make an AsyncTask to check the file online.
2. In that AsyncTasks' onPostExecute, make an AlertDialog
3. If user clicks yes on that AlertDialog, call another AsyncTask to handle updating.